AWS Sagemaker endpoint FastAPI app - Model Error
I've been working on deploying a simple ML model in a FastAPI web app. I'm using AWS Sagemaker endpoint and I send a request to my endpoint from a lambda function, but I keep getting the following error:
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from model with message \"Internal Server Error\". See https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=xxxxxxx#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/xxxxx in account xxxxxxxxx for more information.",
  "errorType": "ModelError",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 12, in lambda_handler\n    response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 565, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 1021, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}

The web app is containerized in a docker container that I pushed to the ECR repository. Here is the docker file:
`FROM python:3.9-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8080", "--config", "settings.py" , "app:app", "-n"]`
The Pytorch model is stored in a .pth file inside the docker image and I'm loading it in my API to make inferences.
Model settings:
model settings
Endpoint settings:
Type: Serverless
Because the app works in my local machine (tested running the container and run predictions), I'm suspecting that the source of error might be related to the endpoint settings, but was not able to figure it out. Can anyone help please?

What endpoints do you have defined in the application? I know it is not the same scenario, but for batch transform jobs, you need to define a GET /ping endpoint that return 200, which I think it is used for determining the app is running as expected. And then the POST /invocations endpoint is used for getting the predictions.

Hi Francisco, thank you for your comment. I've created the endpoint similar to what you have explained. GET /ping for health check and POST /invocations for getting the predictions.
